# How to detect that a result value of a formula has changed

Tags: excel, vba

I do not find a way to detect when a cell with a formula has changed its result value.

For example, if I have the following cell:

[image]

and I update its value, it becomes like this:

[image]

It is done by Visual Basic, when it detects a change in the cell content, it increases the cell version (the VALVER value).

I want to increase that number also when a formula result has been changed. My code is not working in that case because the formula update its result when other cells change their value.

As the content of the formula cell have not change, but the resulting value, the code does not detect a change so it does not update the version.

The following code is what I use to detect cell changes:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cell As Range

    ' For each cell and only if with our references 
    For Each cell In Target.Cells
        If (Not cell.Comment Is Nothing) Then
            If (cell.Comment.Text() Like "*" & PropertyReferenceHeader & "*") Then
                ' Update the version of the cell and change the background as update pending
                RewriteCellComment cell, False, True
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

How can I call my function 'RewriteCellComment' when a formula updates its value?

Comment: There is no event that tells you that the result of a formula changed. The only thing you can track are changes of those cells the formula references.

Comment: Maybe `Worksheet_Calculate()` could be used?

Comment: One possible solution is to handle the Worksheet Calculate event, which is fired every time the sheet calculates. The event comes after all the calculations have finished. In effect you have to maintain a list of cell references for those cells you are interested in (maybe using Names to refer to the cells), and their previous value. When the Calculate event is fired, you run through this list and compare the current (possibly new) value to the previous value.

Comment: Use an UDF instead of a formula?

Comment: The problem is that I do not know where the formulas are. This macros should go in excels that are constantly changing, so users can move, create or delete the formulas, so I cannot depend on storing the formulas position.

Comment: How do the cells get the comment in the first place? Your SheetChange() handler only works on cells that already have a comment. If a user creates a formula in a new cell, how does that cell get a comment?

Comment: The comment is set by the user with another macro inserted in a button inside the menu displayed when right clicking the cell.